# Android - ScrollView skips vertical finger gesture after a short distance

Tags: android, scrollview, skip, motion

I've got a class that extends EditText and overwrites the onTouchEvent()-method in order to see when the corresponding MotionEvents occur:

```js
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {
    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int i) {
        super(context, attrs, i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: Log.v("ME", "down");
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: Log.v("ME", "up");
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: Log.v("ME", "move");
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: Log.v("ME", "cancel");
        break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

When the View isn't inside a `ScrollView`, everything works as expected: LogCat prints "move" as long as my finger is moving around on the screen.
But when the View is inside a `ScrollView` and I'm moving my finger vertically, LogCat prints some "move", after a couple of millimeters a "cancel" and then nothing anymore until I replace my finger on the screen. This doesn't happen when I move horizontally.

I think the reason is that at this point the `ScrollView` recognizes that it should start scrolling now and consequently "steals" the MotionEvents from the View in order to evaluate them itself.

My question is now: How can I prohibit this behaviour without creating a new class extending `ScrollView`?

Thanking you in anticipation

Daniel R.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you ***try*** to `setOnTouchListener`

ex:

```
ScrollView yourScrollView;
yourScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
    public boolean  onTouch  (View v, MotionEvent event){
        yourTextView.onTouch(yourTextView,event);
    }
});
```

something in these lines.. please report back so I could edit the answer to the best

Answer (score 0):

(It's me, DanielR. I've now got my own account, sorry for that.)

Thanks a lot for the rapid answer, Sherif. That solves my problem. 
What I am actually doing in my app is viewing a scrollable `EditText` that has 3 areas: a small margin on the left and the right in which you can scroll the View and a main area in the centre in which the common editing actions are performed.
What I am doing to achieve this, is:

1. when the user starts a gesture in the margins, I set the onTouchListener to `null`, so the `ScrollView`'s scrolling action is performed (read that in a post somewhere around here).

2. touching the main area, the onTouchListener is set to the one you suggested above, so scrolling is disabled AND all touch events reach the EditText. Previously, my onTouchListener was empty so merely scrolling was prohibited. I don't know why I didn't see that myself. I think it's just too late ;)

Once again, thank you a lot.

Comment: You should accept Sherif's post as the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I would do so, but as I wrote above, my visitor's account I used to ask that question is gone. I'm really sorry for that.